# Sample REST Observable service and a remote subscriber client in Java 9/RxJava 2

Tags: rx-java2, java-9

**Here is the background:** 
 We have  a cluster (of 3) different services deployed on various containers (like Tomcat, TomEE, JBoss) etc.  Each of the services does one thing. Like one service manages a common DB and provides REST services to CRUD the db. One service puts some data into a JMS Queue, Another service reads from the Queue and updates the DB.  There is a client app that makes a REST service call to one of the service that sets off creating a row in the db, pushing that row into a queue etc.

**Question**: We need to implement the client app so that we know at any given point in time where the processing is. How do I implement this in RcJava 2/Java 9?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to determine what functionality in RxJava 2 will benefit you.

- Coordination between asynchronous sources. Since you have a) event-driven requests from one side, and b) network queries on the other sides, this is a good fit so far.
- Managing a stream of data, transforming and combining from one or more sources. You have given no indication that this is required.

Second, you need to determine what RxJava 2 does *not* provide:

- Network connections. This is provided by your existing libraries.
- Database management. Again, this is provided in your existing solutions.

Now, you have to decide whether the firstlies add up to something you can benefit from, given the up-front costs of learning a new library.

Comment: Good point Bob.  I was thinking if the service(s) become observables and the client app becomes the subscriber then the subscriber is woken when each of the services is finished.  Then the subscriber say using the zip operator can determine if the client can decide if the actual service call (the one that initiates several activities such as creating a row in db, push that record into queue, read from queue and update the db etc.) has completed or not.  The regular way would be to poll each app for the status.  I am still investigating what technology to use.